# What is "the index-linked variety"?

Tags: bonds, rate-of-return, forecasting

I am reading [this article](https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2021/03/15/young-people-stand-to-make-dismal-returns-on-their-investments) on The Economist.

It says that the new generation will gather lower returns on investments than the previous generations.

The authors estimated the future return on equities as follows:

> they assume that the real return on equities will be equal to the inflation-adjusted return on a risk-free asset (represented by Treasury bills), which they estimate at -0.5%, plus a “risk premium” for buying equities of about 3.5%, for a real return of just 3%

and the future return on bonds as follows:

> For bonds, the authors assume the current, negative real yields on the index-linked variety

What is the "index-linked variety"?

How the return on bonds got estimated exactly?

Comment: Keep in mind, this is one (well, actually 2) person's opinion. Buy a year end copy of any financial publication in which they offer a group of people forecasting the next year. The forecasts are all over the place. I know authors who have insisted the market has been too high, for decades. They felt vindicated by a crappy 2000's, yet, Jan 1, 2000 to present? A CAGR of 8.19%, or a 282% total return. They never said to get back in.

Comment: Do remember that economists only exist to make astrologers look good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the article (or at least what you have posted since it's behind a paywall) is looking at "real", or inflation-adjusted, returns, I assume that by "index-linked", they mean bonds whose principal is adjusted based on some inflation index like the Consumer Price Index (CPI).

Like most other financial instruments, they are priced by the market. Investors will price these bonds based on what they think inflation will be in future years (depending on the length of the bond). If inflation is higher than expected, the bonds will increase in value, and vice-versa.

So the yield (return) of these bonds is an indication of what "the market" thinks inflation will be in the future. A "negative real yield" means that interest rates are lower than what the market thinks inflation will be over the same time period. So the return on bonds are expected to be more than eaten away by inflation.

Comment: ah sure, "the index-linked variety" as the bonds whose coupons are a function of the inflation rate. Thanks

Comment: Actually the _principal_ is adjusted by the inflation rate, not the coupons, but I don;t think that's a huge distinction for your question.